# Injector Error "Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!"

Tags: angular

I tried to create an **HttpInterceptor** to add some headers for authorization to every http that happens. I need to get the headers from a service called **AuthService**. Here is the code below:

Interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }
}
```

AuthService:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

AppModule:

```
providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  }, AuthService]
```

I receive the following error:

> Error: Provider parse errors:
>       Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! InjectionToken_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule
>   in ./AppModule@-1:-1

I already checked the previous answers but I don't understand where the cyclic dependency was detected. What I am trying to do is described here: https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-new-headers

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Look at this [GitHub Discussion (Issue #18224)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224)

As a workaround you can use `Injector` manually and inject relevant service inside `intercept` method: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224#issuecomment-316957213

> I resolved simply not setting authService in constructor but getting
>   in the intercept function.
>
> ```
> intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
>     // Get the auth header from the service.
>     const auth = this.inj.get(AuthenticationService);
>     const authToken = auth.getAuthorizationToken();
>     ...
> }
> ```

---

**UPDATE:**

Prior to Angular `4.3.0` unfortunately it's impossible to use `Injector` manually inside `intercept` method:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

So there is one more workaround using `rxjs`:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const authService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService)
            observer.next(authService.getAuthorizationHeader())
            observer.complete()
        })
    })
        .mergeMap((Authorization: string) => {
            let authReq = req

            if (Authorization) {
                authReq = req.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization
                    }
                })
            }

            return next.handle(authReq)
        })
}
```

Comment: perfect solution, saved my day.

Comment: If you get this: `http.interceptor.ts:64 Uncaught TypeError: $.a.create(...).mergeMap is not a function` That means you are importing the wrong mergeMap `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';`

Comment: got the same issue with angular 6 and solved with method here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224#issuecomment-329939990

Answer (score 6):

Remove AuthService from providers list as it is imported in the Interceptor already thus the cyclic dependency.

Comment: AuthService is used in many parts of my application and I need the same instance everywhere. Any option?

Comment: I think I fixed the issue but it looks stupid... I splitted the authService into two. In one file I got all the variables and on the other all the http requests. This way I only require the variables on my Interceptor eliminating the cyclic dependency. Is this an anti-pattern or should I keep it? Anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: @itsUndefined How did you split your service class into two ? is it like two seperate classes deriving from the base service class ?

Comment: @KunalS It isn't looking the best but I split it so that there are two service classes that are independent on each other. In the first service I have all the  variables about authentication like tokens, username etc. In the second service I only register the observables to access the backend. This way the http import and dependency injection is only required for the second service that does not access authentication variables. On my login component I import both services. I send the request from the second service. I receive the response and set the variables on the first service.

Comment: This way my interceptor that sets the authentication header only has to access the first service that does not depend on the http import. Problem solved

Answer (score 3):

Remove following from AuthService -

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

The reason is - HttpClient using interceptor internally and interceptor using AuthService and AuthService is using HttpClient. thus it gives "cyclic dependency" error.

Comment: The problem was fixed when angular 5.2.3 came out. The pull request that fixed the issue can be seen here: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19809

Comment: Agree, I face this issue in 5.2.0 version.