# Load configuration at run time

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project where I can build the project for a given environment and run it. I've realized this bakes the environment settings into the built project. Now I want to load the environment-specific settings at run time.

So, I've currently got this:

```
import { EnvConfig } from '../../../../../tools/env/env-config.interface';

export const Config: EnvConfig = JSON.parse('<%= ENV_CONFIG %>');
```

Where `<%= ENV_CONFIG %>` gets replaced with the baked environment settings. Other files import `Config` and then use it directly like:

```
import { Config } from '../shared/config/env.config';

export function main() {
    console.log(`Environment: ${Config.ENV}`);
}
```

I've been looking at something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47110796/1680677), but it seems I'd have to switch everything from using `Config` directly to using an injected `ConfigService`.

**Do I need to switch from a constant to a service in order to support the run-time load? If not, how do I create the constant on the fly?**

Comment: Have a look here.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938411/1160794 You can keep using your Config variable, which will get initialised once from a service before the app loads

Comment: I'll also note that I needed this to avoid a circular dependency: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47097841/1680677](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47097841/1680677).

Comment: Not if you use angular 5.2.3 or greater https://stackoverflow.com/a/48683766/1160794