# ERROR Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! AuthenticationService

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

I have recently upgraded my cli to Angular 10. My project was running alright before I upgraded to Material 10 and it requires individual import of component modules. After finishing he change, my localhost is not running and getting these errors:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! AuthenticationService
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.js:5596)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11285)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11111)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24243)
    at Object.get (core.js:22142)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:4079)
    at NodeInjector.get (core.js:4263)
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:29)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (app.component.ts:66)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:4184)

ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> [object Object] -> AuthenticationService -> Http -> Http -> Http]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63832:27)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73941:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73941:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73941:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63718:33)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63722:57)
    at Object.AuthenticationService_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:5049:295)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74108:35)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73930:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63718:33)
```

The solution I tried is
[Injector Error "Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654351/injector-error-provider-parse-errors-cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency)

But the error is still not going, and I am completely clueless where this is going cyclic.
FYI, here is the code snippet:

app.module.ts

```
import { CommonService } from './shared/services/common.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
// import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { PerfectScrollbarModule, PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './shared/inmemory-db/inmemory-db.service';
// import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { rootRouterConfig } from './app.routing';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './shared/interceptor/tokenInterceptor';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AuthenticationService, AuthGuard, AdminGuard } from './shared/services/auth';
import { NgxPermissionsModule } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { Globals } from './shared/services/globals';
import { UserService} from './shared/services/user.service';
import { ApiService} from './shared/services/api.service';
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './shared/helpers/error.interceptor';
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './shared/helpers/fake-backend';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { passThruUnknownUrl: true }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: false })
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    fakeBackendProvider,
    AuthenticationService, CommonService, AuthGuard, AdminGuard, CookieService, Globals, UserService, ApiService,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CustomUrlBaseService } from './customurlbase';
import { User } from './../../models/user';
import { NavigationService } from '../navigation.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService extends CustomUrlBaseService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public currentUser: Observable<User>;
    tokenKey = 'currentUserGG';
    loginApiRoot = '/api/account';

    constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService,
      private http: Http, private cookieService: CookieService) {
      super();
      let curu;
      try {
        curu = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUserGG'));
      } catch {}
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(curu);
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): User {
      return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const body =  { 'phoneNumber': username.toString(), 'otp': password.toString() };
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/LoginbyOtp`, body)
    .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
      const res = response.json();
        if (res['success'] === 1) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUserGG', JSON.stringify(res['user']));
          localStorage.setItem('UserMenu', JSON.stringify(res['menu']));
          localStorage.setItem('DefaultSettings', JSON.stringify(res['settings']));
          localStorage.setItem('AccessRoutes', JSON.stringify(res['accessroutes']));
          this.cookieService.set('curStage', JSON.stringify(res['stage']));
          this.currentUserSubject.next(res['user']);
          this.navigationService.publishNavigationChange('icon-menu');
          return {status: res['success'], user: res['user']};
        }
        return {status: res['success'], user: ''};
    }));
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUserGG');
    localStorage.removeItem('UserMenu');
    localStorage.removeItem('DefaultSettings');
    localStorage.removeItem('AccessRoutes');
    localStorage.clear();
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Renderer2, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RoutePartsService } from './shared/services/route-parts.service';
import { ThemeService } from './shared/services/theme.service';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService} from './shared/services/auth/authentication.service';
import { User, Role } from './shared/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  appTitle = '';
  pageTitle = '';
  currentUser: User;
  authenticationService;

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    public title: Title,
    private router: Router,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private routePartsService: RoutePartsService,
    private themeService: ThemeService,
    private renderer: Renderer2) {
      this.authenticationService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
      this.authenticationService.currentUser?.subscribe(x => this.currentUser = x);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changePageTitle();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.themeService.applyMatTheme('ecom-blue');
  }
  changePageTitle() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(
        (routeChange) => {
      const routeParts = this.routePartsService.generateRouteParts(this.activeRoute.snapshot);
      if (!routeParts.length) {
        return this.title.setTitle(this.appTitle);
      }
      // Extract title from parts;
      this.pageTitle = routeParts
                      .reverse()
                      .map((part) => part.title )
                      .reduce((partA, partI) => {return `${partA} > ${partI}`;
                    });
      this.pageTitle += ` | ${this.appTitle}`;
      this.title.setTitle(this.pageTitle);
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  get isAdmin() {
    return this.currentUser && this.currentUser.role === Role.Admin;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you solve the problem? because I am facing the same one.